# mongoDB - Delete a document which is an object

Tags: mongodb

I would like to delete the document displayed on the image but this document is an object ("{}"), how can I delete it? thank you !

https://zupimages.net/up/20/18/jdfq.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly but it seems like you want to use [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)

```
db.collection.updateOne({_id: documentID}, {$unset: {"modules.SHOPECO.test": ""}})
```

This will remove the field `test` from the `modules.SHOPECO` object from the specific document, you want also use [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) instead of `updateOne` if you want this to happen on multiple documents.

Comment: Thank's you very much !